# jquery - removing loading div after the page has loaded

Tags: jquery, loader, pageload

So I created a simple method to put a loader. I put a loader already and put the opacity of a main container tag to 0.4 . but when page loads, my javascript doesn't remove the loader and set opacity to 1. So my code here:

> Important Notes:
>   I use JQuery version 2(I don't know the exact)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(this).load(function() {
          $('.progress').hide();
          $('body').css("opacity", "1");
       });
    });
```

Comment: opacity of 1 means *fully visible*. Nothing in your code *removes* your loader unless `.progress` matches your loader, which wouldn't make sense if the next line is meant to match it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: That seems to be what he/she is saying at the end of the question, yes: *"Note that load is a tag I put as my own custom tag"* But we still need to see the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(window).load()` not `$(document).load()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    alert("This can run");
  });
  $(this).load(function(){
    alert("This cannot run");
  });
  $(document).load(function(){
    alert("This cannot run too");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misunderstanding opacity. Setting opacity to 1 means that the element is **fully visible**, not transparent at all. So `$("load").css("opacity", 1)` makes sure the `load` element is fully visible. *(Lurkers: the OP says they have a custom element type, so that selector isn't actually wrong.)*

If you want to *remove* it, `remove` it:

```
$("load").remove();
```

If you want to *hide* it, `hide` it:

```
$("load").hide();
```

If you want to make it fully transparent, set opacity to 0:

```
$("load").css("opacity", 0);
```